# Show interstitial ad after every 'x' number of button clicks Flutter Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, admob, interstitial

Hi I have an app that shows quotes randomly with the press of a button. I want to show Interstitial ads on every 10th click. I am a noob, and can't find the best way to implement it.

However, I have built code that enables ad to be show for the first time the button is clicked (very basic, ik). But it doesn't repeat the ad on every 10th click. Here's the code:

````
  void _createInterstitialAd() {
    InterstitialAd.load(
      adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712', // test ad ids for different platforms

      request: AdRequest(),

      adLoadCallback: InterstitialAdLoadCallback(
        // if ad fails to load
        onAdFailedToLoad: (LoadAdError error) {
          print('Ad exited with error: $error'); // print error
        },

        // else
        onAdLoaded: (InterstitialAd ad) {
          setState(() {
            this._interstitialAd = ad; // set the ad equal to the current ad
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }


  void showInterstitial() async {
    _interstitialAd.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
      onAdShowedFullScreenContent: (InterstitialAd ad) =>
          print('Ad Showed'),
      onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (InterstitialAd ad) =>
          ad.dispose(),
      onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (InterstitialAd ad, AdError error) {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
        ad.dispose();
      },
      onAdImpression: (InterstitialAd ad) => print('Impression'),
    );
    _interstitialAd.show();
  }```
````

Comment: you can add counter add the value after x amount of time and then show the add.

Answer (score 0):

Make a variable `clickcount` and put initial value 0,
then implement this method in any button onpressed.

```
setState(() {
  clickcount = clickcount + 1;
  if (clickcount > 10) {
    showInterstitialAd();
    clickcount = 0;
  }
});
```